# SSRS time out issue

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created a SSRS report in SharePoint and its uploaded in to the SharePoint library. While running, its working fine. It taking less than 10 seconds to load the report. But If I kept the report in idle mode for the next 5 minutes, then I tried to enter the text in search box in report tool and then clicked find. But instead of displaying the result, it loads the report again. And If I pass the search criteria, it will works. So My assumption is  that, it would be the problem of time out. So can you guys advise me where can I update the time out value to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If this is SSRS SharePoint integrated mode I guess something should be available in Central Admin to which usually developers might not be having acces atleast in prod environment. Check with the administrators who manage your farm.